# WPF4 Unleashed - how does converting child elements work?

Tags: wpf, xaml

In chapter 2 of the book **WPF4 Unleashed** the author shows an example of how XAML processes type conversion. He states that

```
<SolidColorBrush>White</SolidColorBrush>
```

is equivalent to

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
```

, because a string can be converted into a `SolidColorBrush` object.

But how is that enough? It doesn't make sense to me. How does XAML know to which property should the value `White` be assigned?

Comment: The sentence directly after your example explains: `In this case, the first XAML snippet works because a type converter exists that can convert strings such as "White" (or "white" or "#FFFFFF") into a SolidColorBrush object.` What are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: How does it know that `Color` should "be" `White`, instead of some other property, e.g. `Color2`, which also is of type `Color`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a core feature of XAML.  Microsoft's [XAML Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) covers this rather explicitly.

> A small number of XAML elements can directly process text as their content. To enable this, one of the following cases must be true:
>
> - The class must declare a content property, and that content property must be of a type assignable to a string (the type could be Object). For instance, any ContentControl uses Content as its content property and it is type Object, and this supports the following usage on a practical ContentControl such as a Button: Hello.
> - The type must declare a type converter, in which case the text content is used as initialization text for that type converter. For example, Blue. This case is less common in practice.
> - The type must be a known XAML language primitive.

That is, the `SolidColorBrush` class is able to route text content to its `Color` property, by declaring "Color" as its content property.

Most likely the separate `Color` class has an implicit cast from `string`, allowing a valid string to be sent for any purpose that specifies a `Color`.

Comment: The book says that `Color` is not designated as the content property. That's where my confusion comes from.

Comment: The internal practice doesn't really matter; there could also be a type converter, or color could just be defined among the language primitives.